# Default Time out for Collection Aggregator Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Do any one knows, What is the default Timeout for Collection Aggregator in Mule?

I was reading multiple documents but I didnt find anywhere  default timeout period for Collection Aggregator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in the code, the default value is 0 (that means forever) and is inherited from [AbstractAggregator](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/routing/AbstractAggregator.java#L46).

Comment: Which means, It will wait until all the requests getting aggregated?. With the default timeout,and in my case, I have splitter which splits the xml in to multiple small xml and finally aggregator. If suppose, one of the xml is broken inbetween and it not able to reach aggragator, what will happen in this case?. Aggregator will wait for forever?.

Comment: I haven't tried just read the code, but following what I have seen: yes, it will wait as much as the requesting thread can wait.